# ENOENT: no such file or directory in nestjs deployment

Tags: nestjs, vercel

I'm reading json file in my file directory and works file in

```
const data = await readFile(join(process.cwd(),'./src/test/data/test/test.json'), 'utf8')
```

It is not being read in production in vercel.

Tried by directly giving the file path without join.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this would mean that the file path you're trying to read doesn't exist on your production server. Find the correct path and re-adjust the path string

Comment: It got resolved after i corrected the path